# Totally lost – data binding expressions inside GridView’s template

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

1) On aspx page we define GridView control named **gvwPolls**, and inside its template we define a user control named **pollBox1**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="objPolls" ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                Question is : <%# Eval("QuestionText") %> <br />
                <mb:PollBox ID="PollBox1" runat="server" PollID='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objPolls" ...></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

a) I assume that inside **gvwPolls’s** template, the **gvwPollBox1.DataBind** is called before `PollID='<%# Eval("ID") %>'` and `<%# Eval("QuestionText") %>` expressions get evaluated?!

b) Can someone offer some explanation how or why is **gvwPollBox1.DataBind** called before `PollID='<%# Eval("ID") %>'` and `<%# Eval("QuestionText") %>` expressions get evaluated?

2) Continuing with the above example:

-- **pollBox1** user control defines a Repeater control named **rptOptions**:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptOptions">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("pollBoxTitle") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

-- In **pollBox1’s** code-behind file we bind **rptOptions** to a data source inside **DoBinding()** method.

-- We also override **pollBox1’s DataBind()** method:

```
  public override void DataBind()
  {
      base.DataBind();
      DoBinding();
  }
```

a) I assume that due to overriding **pollBox1.DataBind()**, the data binding expression `<%# Eval("pollBoxTitle") %>` ( defined inside **rptOptions’s** template ) will get evaluated prior to a call to **DoBinding** method? If so, won’t then `<%# Eval("pollBoxTitle") %>`  get evaluated before **rptOptions** is actually bound to a data source?

b) If that is the case, how then is **rptOptions** able to extract value ( from data source’s **pollBoxtitle property**)  from a data source, if at the time the `<%# Eval("pollBoxTitle") %>`
expression got evaluated, **rptOptions** wasn’t yet bound to any data source?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why the page life cycle is the way that is, probably has something to do with rendering childs before the parent object. When exactly do you call .DataBind() in the PollBox control? Try to move it into an event that is later in the life cycle, like PreRender.

There is also another way to ensure it is working the way you want to:
Subscribe to the RowDataBound Event, use .FindControl("YourPollBoxID") to get the instance of the control current bound row, set the properties and perform a manuall .DataBind();